# Successful npm package release not showing on npm.js

Tags: node.js, git, npm, package, semantic-versioning

I have a package called [garba-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/garba-ui), basically a very basic company ui library.

Thing is everything was working ok until yesterday when I tried to make a release patch via CLI.
I got this:

[image: CLI release feedback]

But in the npm.js page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/garba-ui) and all subsequent updates in other projects, I get this:

[image]

I deleted git tags, local and remote. I tried to re-release it and got the same results over and over again. I am logged in, and everything else seems to be working just fine. I so I think (any creative idea welcomed here).

Even my local package.json got updated during the release proccess:

```
{
  "name": "garba-ui",
  "version": "3.1.9",
  "description": "Garba UI will contain all common UI components to be 
shared among all company projects.",
  "main": "app/lib/garbaui.js",
  "author": [ ... ],
   ...
}
```

But anything in the page seems to reflect this update.
Any idea what might have happened or how can I get things to work again?

Again: everything was working just fine until yesterday.

Comment: When I go to that link, I get: 3.1.11 is the latest of 19 releases.  Have you resolved this issue on your own?

Comment: Yes, somehow it worked itself out when versions got updated. The downside is that there are a couple of versions between 1.8 and 1.11 that don't work. That's not right, but was the best I could do. Thanks!

Comment: So this was probably a stale cache somewhere.  If you see it again, immediately delete your browser cache, close all your browsers, delete everything in %tmp% that isn't being held by something and then look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it worked itself by releasing another version. The downside is that there are a couple of versions between 1.8 and 1.11 that don't work and should be skipped.

It's not right but it was the best I could do.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer so folks won't be coming in here looking for problems to solve.  Also, don't forget to remove the broken versions from your feed.